# How can I increase the font size in the Help system?

Tags: macos, high-sierra

If I open the Help for an application, the size of the font is (for me) quite small. Is there any way to increase the size of the font?

By "Help", I mean the help system/viewer that is presented after pressing <kbd>⌘ command</kbd><kbd>?</kbd> or selecting the help option from the **Help** menu bar item in many applications. Once the Help system opens a window and text is visible, pressing <kbd>⌘ command</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> does not have an effect. I could not find any obviously-relevant options in the macOS System Preferences, though I may have missed something.

**Update 2020-12-18**: I was wrong – I was actually pressing <kbd>⌘ command</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>, *not* <kbd>⌘ command</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>, and that's why it didn't work. In [one of the comments](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408702/how-can-i-increase-the-font-size-in-the-help-system#comment570650_408704), I explain what led to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click into the text area and just press <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did already try that (as I tried to explain in my original posting). ⌘+ does nothing, at least in macOS 10.13.6.

Comment: Correction. It _does_ work. I don't understand what is happening. I tried repeatedly, originally and in response to your answer, after clearly clicking in the window. I tried a few more times just now, with different pages, and it worked. I'm baffled, but I don't care, so long as it works.

Comment: I now figured out what I was doing wrong, and want to alert other people that may be doing the same thing. A lot of applications like Safari have a similar increase-font-size keyboard shortcut, but they use `⌘=` (without the shift key), which is on the same key as `+`. I've been using `⌘=` for so many years and internalized it as `⌘+` (because that's what it looks like on the keyboard), that I didn't even realize I _wasn't_ pressing the shift key when I tried to use it in the help system. The help system really, really wants `⌘+` (with the shift key).